# listview search in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

```
    <ul id='list' data-role='listview' data-filter='true' data-inset='false'>
    <li id='a1'>
        <h3>ABC</h3>
        <p>this is ABC</p>
    </li>
    <li id='a2'>
        <h3>DEF</h3>
        <p>DEF is not ABC</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

for example,

search 'ABC', result is ABC and DEF.

but I don't want to search `<p>`tag, search only `<h3>`tag.

how do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well... here is a start...

```
$("#list li").each(function(){

    if($(this).
              find("h3").
              text().toUpperCase().
              indexOf(SEARCHWORD.toUpperCase()) >=0)
       $(this).show();
    else
       $(this).hide();

});
```

[**See a Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DyYFb/)

Answer (score 4):

From the jQuery mobile [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html):

You can either bind to the callback internally by defining `$.mobile.listview.prototype.options.filterCallback`, or by attaching the filter callback after the widget is made. (`$("#mylist").listview('option', 'filterCallback', yourFunction);`)

The function you give must take 2 arguments, the first being the text of any of the ul's being searched, and the second being the value being searched for.

In your case you want to only search in the header portion, so your filter function should strip out everything after the header tag and then apply a search on the remainder.

```
var searchHeader = function(text, search) {
    // Strip out extra tags from text
    return text.toLowerCase().indexOf( search ) === -1;
}
$("#list").listview('option', 'filterCallback', searchHeader);
```

Answer (score 4):

Add following data attribute for custom search. Its the **easiest** way.

```
<li data-filtertext="ABC"><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
<li data-filtertext="DEF"><a href="#">United States</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more concise way would be e.g.

```
$('#list li h3').each(function(){
    alert($(this).html().search('ABC') == 0 )
});
```